# Search query box doesn't recommend places in Vue automatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

If you run my below code, it is supposed to open up a website. This works fine, however, when I go to the input box it is supposed to recommend places with the characters given immediately. This isn't working.

I am doing a tutorial and am currently at 12:41 of this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pTzHoliXUQ&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9hfoy8vFQ5tbXO3vY0xhhUZ&index=5

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <main class="container text-white" >
    <div class="pt-4 mb-8 relative">
      <input type="text" 
      v-model = "searchQuery"
      @input="getSearchResults"
      placeholder="Search for city or state" 
      class="py-2 px-1 w-full bg-transparent border-b
       focus:border-weather-secondary focus:outline-none focus:shadow-[0px_1px_0_0_#004E71]">
       <ul class="absolute bg-weather-secondary text-white w-full shadow-md py-2 px-1 top-[66px]">
        <li v-for="searchResult in mapboxSearchResults" :key ="searchResult.id" class="py-2 cursor-pointer">
          {{searchResult.place_name}}
        </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const mapboxAPIkey ="pk.eyJ1IjoiYWhhbmFhYSIsImEiOiJjbGJqc3d5NG0xNGd5M3BtbWppcmgyNzE4In0.L-HsHWAbshfvVY_xixizNw"

const searchQuery = ref("");
const queryTimeout = ref(null)
const mapboxSearchResults = ref(null)

const getResults = () => {
  clearTimeout(queryTimeout.value)
  queryTimeout.value = setTimeout(async() => {
    if(searchQuery.value !== ""){
      const result = await axios.get(
        `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${searchQuery.value}.json?access_token=${mapboxAPIkey}&types=place`
      )
      mapboxSearchresults.value = result.data.features
      return;
    }
    mapboxSearchresults.value = null
  }, 300)

}
</script>
```

I tried to run the code with npm run dev in the terminal and everything was working fine up until now.

Comment: did you find any error message in the console?

Comment: It seems you are calling a function `getSearchResults` on input event but you do not have that function in your code instead you have a function named `getResults`. Can you match the function names?

Comment: Thank you neha, but even after matching function names, it still doesnt work